# How can I use for loop in a IN statement in this situation?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, for-loop

I am using for loop for select in. The issue I am encounter is I have multiple value in the IN statement. I know `IN(term_1, term_2)` we need a period to separate each one. When I use for loop, I don't know how to append the period. First, it was inside the statement parenthesis instead of at the end.

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i <= 8; $i++) {
    $stm =$db->prepare("SELECT id FROM sign WHERE term IN (:term_$i) GROUP BY os.user_id order by COUNT(os.user_id) DESC ");

        $stm->bindParam(":term_$i", $search_text[$i]);

        $stm->execute();
    }

?>
```

Comment: You can't do that. I mean, you can but you won't get more than one value in your IN statement. Prepared statements kind of fail with IN statements. You have to build it all out yourself and escape the values yourself.

Comment: Thank you! How about if I don't use prepare statement or mysql prepared, I have not tried that yet. But will when I have time. Thanks for you time.

Comment: @Halfstop - Actually you can build the prepared statement from a simple array, using `trim(str_repeat('?, ', count($values)), ',')` to set a simple `?` placeholder for the `IN` statement, then passing the values to bind as an array in your `execute()`

Comment: @MarkBaker Right build it all out yourself and stuff it in the prepared statement. There's no way to do it that isn't hackish.

Comment: @Halfstop - but you're not reverting to quoting and escaping values, still using prepared statement, so what's so hacky about my approach?

Comment: @MarkBaker No, you're correct, that is the best way to do it. You still get the benefit of the prepared statement. That should be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Prepared statement placeholders can only represent SINGLE values.

e.g.

```
$foo = '1,2,3';
$db->prepare("SELECT ... WHERE foo in (:foo)");
bind(':foo', $foo);
```

would create a query that's interpreted as

```
SELECT ... WHERE foo IN ('1,2,3');
```

Note the quotes - your three separate numbers are now a single-valued string, and the query runs as if it had been written:

```
SELECT ... WHERE foo='1,2,3'
```

You'd have to build a dynamic statement and create as many placeholders as you have values.

```
foreach ($values as $val) {
     $placeholders[] = '?';
}
$sql = "SELECT ... WHERE foo IN (" . implode(',', $placeholders) . ")";
...prepare/bind other values
$stmt->execute($values);
```

Comment: `$sql = sprintf('SELECT ... WHERE foo IN (%s)', implode(',', array_fill(0, count($values), '?')));`

Answer (score 0):

im afraid you're gonna have to do it the old fashion way

```
$stm ="SELECT id FROM sign WHERE term IN (";
for ($i = 0; $i <= 8; $i++) {
$stm.="'";
$stm.=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$search_text[$i]);
$stm.="'";
}
$stm.=") GROUP BY os.user_id order by COUNT(os.user_id) DESC ";
$db->query($stm);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$sep = ''; $lst = '';
for ($i = 0; $i <= 8; $i++) {
    $lst .= $sep."'".$search_text[$i]."'";
}
$stm =$db->query("SELECT id FROM sign WHERE term IN ($lst) GROUP BY os.user_id order by COUNT(os.user_id) DESC ");
while ($row = $stm->fetch()) {
    // do something with $row
}
?>
```

This does not use the prepare and so is less secure. You could experiment with creating the whole list using `:term_1, :term_2, ...` and then preparing it and then binding -- that would be more secure and is the direction you should go. But hopefully this code example will show you how to build your sql dynamically.

(If you bind in a loop make sure you use a call-by-reference as in

```
foreach ($search_text as $k=>&$v)
    ...bindParam($k, $v);
```

If you leave off that & then you get problems.)