# Select * from users where username IN () only showing 1 record and when there's 2 it shows none

Tags: php

I am trying to get all of the users within an array, to use for a foreach to show individual records:

```
        $getuser = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username IN (?)");
        $getuser->execute(array($select));
        return $getuser->fetchAll();
```

That's how I am selecting, this is how I run it:

```
$following = $this->model->user('',implode(",",$followingusers));
```

When I print the array and the implode it shows:

```
Array ( [0] => admin [1] => admin2 )
admin,admin2
```

I am trying to use the result in a foreach have only 1 row it shows it, but when there's more than one, it just show a blank page

```
foreach ($following as $follows):

endforeach;
```

edit: I've viewed source and no error is showing and error report is on

Comment: Question has already been answered once this evening - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683604/how-can-i-use-for-loop-in-a-in-statement-in-this-situation

Comment: *"I've viewed source and no error is showing and error report is on"* - What about checking for errors on the SQL side? Do that, and you will see the error. It's clear that you can't bind tables/columns directly.

Comment: You only have one `?` so you can pass only one parameter.

Comment: Typically strings need to be surrounded by quotes in SQL...

Comment: I've tried $getuser = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username IN (".htmlspecialchars($select).")"); which shows Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'admin' in 'where clause' in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by runnning it inside the execute